# Compiler for assembler with SIMD instructions and c# integration

Tags: c#, dll, assembly

I need an assembler compiler which can generate `SIMD` (SSE etc.) opcodes, also it should can generate a .DLLs libraries that can be easly used in C# (Visual Studio 2010).  Alternatively I can use Delphi/C++ compiler with assembler features if its possible.

Comment: Is there a question buried in there somewhere?

Comment: Do you need an assembler or a compiler?  VS2010 will sure do, C++/CLI lets you use intrinsics, inline assembly and can link code that was assembled by ml.exe.  You have all the tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I honestly don't know IF that is your question, but I can confirm that Delphi's built-in assembler - like the C++ compiler* in Visual Studio - support SIMD instructions (different versions of SIMD instruction sets, according to compiler version). And yes, they can be all be used to make DLLs.

(* NB: inline assembly only available for 32-bit platforms in VC++; Delphi supports inline assembly on both 32- and 64-bit)